# Add value to row number in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to add specific value to the row number but this statement doesn't work :

```
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER()+1) OVER(ORDER BY col_1 value DESC) as Row   FROM table
```

what is the correct syntax to do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put the addition after the window function, but before the alias.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col_1, value DESC) + 1 as Row   FROM table
```

... or, you can put it at the beginning if it seems clearer:

```
SELECT 1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col_1, value DESC) as Row   FROM table
```

I also added a comma between `col1` and `value`. I assume those are 2 different columns, and that it was a typo.  Just mentioning for completeness.